# If $m$ and $n$ are odd integers, show that $8$ divides $m^2 − n^2.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $m$ and $n$ are odd integers, show that $8$ divides $m^2 − n^2.$

Wlog, can state that instead of taking integers, take $m,n$ in the domain of non-negative integers.

Let, $m= 2k+1, n = 2l+1, k,l \in \mathbb {N+},$ i.e. natural numbers plus the element $0.$

The term $m^2 − n^2=
(m+n)(m-n) = (2k+1+2l+1)(2k-2l)$ $=2(k+l+1)2(k-l) = 4(k^2-l^2+k-l)$ $= 4((k-l)(k+l+1))$ 
is divisible by $8$ if
either $(k+l+1),$ or $(k-l)$ is divisible by $2.$
But, nothing can be stated about the parity of $k, l.$
To show this, let us take the minimum possible values for $m=3= 2\cdot 1+1, n=5=2\cdot 2+1.$ Here, have $k=1, l=2.$

Then $3+5= 8, 3-5= -2.$ Hence, the product is divisible by $16.$

Hence, not clear why question not asks for divisibility by $16.$

Comment: It is $ 4 (k-l)(k+l\color{red}{+1})$

Comment: $x^2\equiv 1\mod 8$ for every odd $x$ is well known , you can easily see this by considering that one of the factors $x-1$ and $x+1$ must be divisible by $4$ , hence $8\mid x^2-1$. You can also use this argument for $m-n$ and $m+n$ directly.

Comment: $16$ need not be a divisor , see for example $9^2-5^2$

Comment: Take $m=3$, $n=1$, then $m^2-n^2=8$ which is not divisible by 16.

Comment: Why anyone would downvote this is beyond me. This question is a perfect example of trying it first your self and showing your work here, just as we want! A nice side effect is that it is easy to locate the source of the confusion, the one-line comment by inspidintegrator above says it all.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves an upvote. It is not a quality question. In particular, it is very easy to come up with counterexamples where $16$ does not divide $m^2-n^2$. I'm sorry, its a -1 for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your work above, $m^2 - n^2 = 4(k-l)(k+l+1)$

If $k-l$ is even, we're done.

If $k-l$ is odd, $k-l+1$ is even, and thus $k+l+1=(k-l+1)+2l$ is even.

Thus no matter what parity $k-l$ is, $(k-l)(k+l+1)$ is divisible by 2.

And as comments mention, there are examples where $m^2-n^2$ isn't divisible by 16